# Vs2017 Schema Compare Doesnt Detect changes that exist (only on some machines)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

We've run into a problem on a couple of our development team members systems that I'm hoping someone has come across before.

We are using VS2017 and have our database in a database project.

On two of our team members systems, Schema compare has recently stopped picking up changes when they compare their local development databases to the model to update their DBS.

The project builds without error, and I can even take the generated .dacpac ( from those machines) and run it on their database it actually updates with the latest change so it seems like its a problem specific to the schema compare tool.

Also, schema compare can detect the difference between two different databases on their systems. It only is having problems when comparing the model to a database and vice versa.
It's weird because we have 4 other team members who can compare without issue.

I've even had them back up then delete their project folder and do a fresh get from source control just to make sure its not some kind of local corruption in the project. Nothing seems to work.

Has anyone ever seen this kind of issue or point me down a path to look?

Comment: Suffering a similar problem, but not quite the same. If the model project is the source the compare does not detect differences. Swapping the model and database enable it to find the differences. I just checked the `%appdata%\..\Local\Temp` directory - it has no compression.

Answer (score 3):

So for anyone that runs into this problem down the road we finally figured it out.

Apparently on the 2 machines that weren't working, compression had gotten turned on for the 
C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp folder.
apparently .model files are written to this directory when a compare is done.

The compression was causing problems with writing the .model files and it was erroring but the error never made it back to the UI.

We turned off compression on that directory on those machines, cleaned up all the temporary.model files, and now schema compare works again.